# Reducing the space of an hr to the element above

Tags: html, css, margin

Does anybody know how to reduce the space of an `hr` to the element above? My current style looks like this:

```
hr.hrabt {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 7%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

As result, I get following:

[image: Before]

I would like it to look like this though:
[image: After]
I already tried several things not working, like setting the top margin to 0.

Comment: Can you please include the rest of the code?

Comment: Why are you sure that `hr` has this indent? It could be an indentation for `About`.

Comment: Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your post. I can't reproduce your problem and `margin-top:0` does work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, I'd recommend dropping the horizontal rule entirely and simply adding a border to your headings.

```
h1 {
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## method 1 using margins

Add `margin-top:0` to your `hr`'s CSS and `margin-bottom:0` to the `About` CSS.

```css
hr {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 7%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>About</span>
<hr>
```

## method 2 using absolute positioning

```css
hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 7%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>About</span>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the margin About text?
Or change line-height of the About text.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the margin 0. Maybe this can work.

```css
h1{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
hr{
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider drawing the rule with CSS instead of an `<hr>`. You'll have more control over its appearance and position and your html will be cleaner and more semantically correct.

```css
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 150%; /* relative to the text */
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 2px; /* adjust to control vertical distance from the text */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>About</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The space you want to control is just the margin.

```
hr.hrabt { 
 margin: 0.1em auto;
}
```